# How can I use Angular Material Drag n Drop with Flex Layout?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-flex-layout, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to make a grid that can have drag n drop capabilities and be responsive. First I tried using the [grid list](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview) but I couldn't find how to make it responsive to different screen sizes.

I gave up on grid list and I decided to use the [angular flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) library to create my own grid that would be inherently responsive. Then I tried combining that with [Angular Material Drag n Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) but it's not working as it should.

Specifically, I can drag around grid elements but the behavior is unstable at best. Sometimes I can reorder elements, sometimes not. Sometimes I move an element left and it goes right, sometimes the opposite. You get the picture. It's unpredictable. Another issue is that if you drag the element around, random other elements of the grid are appearing and disappearing.

I tried reading the documentation of drag and drop and I'm starting to get the feeling that it's just not supposed to work the way I want it to. Does anyone know of an implementation that might work for me?

Here is my code:

my-component.html

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1%">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid"
       cdkDropList
       [cdkDropListData]="numbers"
       (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

    <div *ngFor="let n of numbers"
         fxFlex="25%"
         fxFlex.md="33%"
         fxFlex.sm="50%"
         fxFlex.xs="100%"
         cdkDrag>
      <div fxLayout="row" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
        Number: {{n}}
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

my-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, CdkDropList, CdkDropListGroup, moveItemInArray } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(CdkDropListGroup) listGroup!: CdkDropListGroup<CdkDropList>;
  @ViewChild(CdkDropList) placeholder!: CdkDropList;

  numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<number[]>) {
    console.log("drop() prev index: " + event.previousIndex + ", cur index: " + event.currentIndex);
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never used Angular Flex Layout but have you tried pure CSS properties like `{ grid-auto-flow: row; }`, `{ grid-template-columns: 4; }`, etc? May be give a look at TailwindCSS which has quite a good options for Flex and Grid. You might get some ideas. FYI: TailwindCSS is a bit difficult to integrate with Angular as of now though.

Comment: I don't know if some looks like this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315566/angular-material-drag-and-drop-multi-row-list/60316486#60316486 is closer than you want, using %, I forked it in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrxckh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: well the two links before is to "swap" elements, this another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60005131/push-last-object-in-array-to-the-next-array/60005961#60005961 is about "reorder"

Comment: @Eliseo thanks I'll look into that ASAP. Also, your first comment, even though it's interesting, doesn't quite cover me because it is not responsive. Sure, it's resizing as you make the screen smaller but I was looking for something like reducing the column number on smaller screens.

Comment: Futhermore, the last it's incompleted, sorry I think that was fullly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried so hard to combine `@angular/flex-layout` and `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` but there were too many issues. So I did it with css flex
and it is responsive.

[angular-drag-drop-flex-wrap](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-flex-wrap?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { CdkDragDrop } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    this.items[event.previousContainer.data.index] = event.container.data.item;
    this.items[event.container.data.index] = event.previousContainer.data.item;
  }
}
```

```css
.categories {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* NEW */
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  cursor: move;
}

.categories-item {
  flex: 1 0 5rem; /* NEW */
  margin: 5px; /* NEW */
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.placeholder {
  flex: 1 0 5rem; /* NEW */
  margin: 5px; /* NEW */
  background-color: white;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5rem;
  border: 1px;
}
.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

```html
<div #contenedor class="categories" cdkDropListGroup>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
        <div class="categories-item" cdkDropList  cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
            [cdkDropListData]="{item:item,index:i}" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="inner" cdkDrag>
                <div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
                {{item}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
{{items|json}}
```